# Compile error initializing struct member with enum class

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, aggregate-initialization, scoped-enums

Following program giving compilation error as following

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Animation: int{
  Hide=0,
  Show,
  Flicker
};

struct Icon {
  int id;
  char name[10];
  Animation currentAnim; 
  Animation nextAnim;
  int isActive; 
};

static struct Icon IconList[]= {
    {1, "Offline", Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1},
    {2, "Training", Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1},
    {0, 0, Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1}
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Doesn't matter";
}
```

**Compilation**

> 23:1: error: cannot convert 'Animation' to 'char' in initialization
> 23:1: error: cannot convert 'Animation' to 'char' in initialization

If I change the last member of **IconsList[]** to this, the compilation error is fixed.

```
{0, "", Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1}
```

Can you explain the reason? Why I am getting such a compilation error message for the case?

**If I use int instead of enum class, I don't face this compilation error**

Comment: What doest that have to do with your enum class??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The error message certainly suggests its relevant.

Comment: if i don't use enum class, i don't face such compilation error

Comment: The second member of the struct is  `char name[10]`, why are you initializing it with 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The braces around the nested initializer lists may be omitted in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization),

> The braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided (omitted), in which case as many initializer clauses as necessary are used to initialize every member or element of the corresponding subaggregate, and the subsequent initializer clauses are used to initialize the following members of the object.

The member `name` is a subaggregate containing 10 elements, the 2nd `0` in the initializer is just used to initialize the 1st element of `name`, then `Animation::Hide` is tried to use to initialize the 2nd and the 3rd element; but `Animation` can't convert to `char` implicitly (as a [scoped enumeration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations)).

> If I use int instead of enum class, I don't face this compilation error

That's because `int` could convert to `char` implicitly. Note that for this case some of the members of `Icon` might be left uninitialized.

You can add braces for nested initializer if your intent is to use `0` to initialize the member `name`; as the effect the 1st element of `name` is initialized as `0`, and all the remaining elements are value-initialized (zero-initialized) to `0` too, juse same as initializing it with `""`.

```
static struct Icon IconList[]= {
    {1, "Offline", Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1},
    {2, "Training", Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1},
    {0, {0}, Animation::Hide, Animation::Hide, 1}
};
```

Comment: `{0}` is kind of a strange way to initialize an empty string. I get that it sequences the explanation but I'd suggest keeping the `""` used in the OP.

Comment: @songyuanyao I can't understand why this question gets negative vote! what's wrong with it!

Comment: As a former colleague said if it doesn't work add more braces!